# Installation stuck at installing packages for openstack.kolla.docker

Tags: linux, centos, openstack

I am a newbie trying to install AIO OpenStack using Kolla Ansible under a virtual environment. I am following the docs at https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html.

I am using the base machine as a centos 8 stream and facing an issue while running the command. Here is the detailed error message I am getting. I have added the docker-ce repo but no luck. Any assistance is highly appreciated

#kolla-ansible -i ./multinode bootstrap-servers

```
TASK [openstack.kolla.docker : Install packages] ************************************************************************************************

task path: /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/openstack/kolla/roles/docker/tasks/install.yml:32

Using module file /root/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/dnf.py

Pipelining is enabled.

<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root

<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'python && sleep 0'

The full traceback is:

File "/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload_0imz5i2d/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py", line 1180, in ensure

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 901, in resolve

raise exc

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {

"changed": false,

"failures": [],

"invocation": {

"module_args": {

"allow_downgrade": false,

"allowerasing": false,

"autoremove": false,

"bugfix": false,

"conf_file": null,

"disable_excludes": null,

"disable_gpg_check": false,

"disable_plugin": [],

"disablerepo": [],

"download_dir": null,

"download_only": false,

"enable_plugin": [],

"enablerepo": [],

"exclude": [],

"install_repoquery": true,

"install_weak_deps": true,

"installroot": "/",

"list": null,

"lock_timeout": 30,

"name": [

"docker-ce"

],

"nobest": false,

"releasever": null,

"security": false,

"skip_broken": false,

"state": "present",

"update_cache": true,

"update_only": false,

"validate_certs": true

}

},

"msg": "Depsolve Error occured: \n Problem: problem with installed package buildah-1:1.24.2-2.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package buildah-1:1.24.2-2.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.24.0-0.7.module_el8.6.0+944+d413f95e.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1:1.23.1-2.module_el8.6.0+954+963caf36.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.22.3-2.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.22.3-2.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.22.3-1.module_el8.5.0+901+79ce9cba.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.22.0-2.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.22.0-2.module_el8.5.0+877+1c30e0c9.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.22.0-0.2.module_el8.5.0+874+6db8bee3.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.21.4-2.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package buildah-1.19.8-1.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64 requires runc >= 1.0.0-26, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package docker-ce-3:20.10.17-3.el8.x86_64 requires containerd.io >= 1.4.1, but none of the providers can be installed\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.2.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64\n - cannot install the best candidate for the job\n - package runc-1.0.0-56.rc5.dev.git2abd837.module_el8.4.0+521+9df8e6d3.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering\n - package runc-1.0.0-64.rc10.module_el8.4.0+522+66908d0c.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering\n - package runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+736+58cc1a5a.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering\n - package runc-1.0.0-73.rc95.module_el8.6.0+1107+d59a301b.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering\n - package runc-1:1.0.3-1.module_el8.6.0+1108+b13568aa.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.8-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.9-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.4.13-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.10-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.4-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64\n - package containerd.io-1.6.6-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64",

"rc": 1,

"results": []

}

localhost : ok=16 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1 skipped=5 rescued=0 ignored=0



Command failed ansible-playbook -e @/etc/kolla/globals.yml -e @/etc/kolla/passwords.yml -e CONFIG_DIR=/etc/kolla -e kolla_action=bootstrap-servers /root/venv/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/kolla-host.yml --verbose --verbose --verbose --inventory ./all-in-one
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I had removed the buildah and podman packages and let the command run again. It worked.